# Describing steps in an equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am always describing the steps on how a formula is achieved or describing the underlying Mathematical principles taken to solve a problem in the `align` environment. But the descriptions are not displayed in the best manner possible. For example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{OrangeRed}#1}}

\begin{document}
Let us show that by completing the square, we can achieve this.
        \begin{align*}
        f(x)&=ax^2+bx+c \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\mbox{ Factor $a$ from $ax^2+bx$. Do you know why?}\\
            &=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\right)+c\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\mbox{ \red{Complete the square by adding $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$.}} \\
            &=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\red{\frac{b^2}{4a^2}} \right)+c\red{-a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}\mbox{~~~Factor and simplify.}\\
            &=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\\
            &=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\\
            &=a(x-h)^2+k
        \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

yeilds:

[image]

which does not display the description properly. If you notice in my code above, I am forcing the descriptions to have a left indent based on the longest line of math display (where the `a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\red{\frac{b^2}{4a^2}} \right)+c\red{-a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}` is found.)

Now here is a different scenario:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{OrangeRed}#1}}

\begin{document}
Let us apply completing the square to the standard form of a quadratic equation, $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

\begin{align*}
    ax^2+bx+c&=0 &\mbox{Divide by $a$, the leading coefficient.}&\\[1.25ex]
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}&=0 &\mbox{Transpose the constant term to the RHS.}&\\[1.25ex]
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x&=-\frac{c}{a}&\mbox{\red{Add $\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)^2$ to both sides.}}&\\[1.25ex]
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&\mbox{Factor the LHS and simplify the RHS.}&\\[1.25ex]
    \left(x+\frac{b}{a}\right)^2&=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}&\mbox{Take the square root of both sides.}&\\[1.25ex]
    x+\frac{b}{a}&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&\mbox{Solve for $x$.}&\\[1.25ex]
    x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&\mbox{\textbf{Quadratic Formula}.}&
    \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

But what happens in this example is that the description is right aligned and not dependent on the longest line of math display. I have read somewhere that using

```
\text{\parbox[t]{2in}{ can be used in mathmode with a very long long long long long long long description}
```

Of course I foresee a drawback as the length of the `parabox` should be calculated on the remaining space of text while staying within the margin.

In summary, I would like the descriptions to be left aligned and dependent on the longest math display or possible split if using the `split` environment for math equations and that if the description goes beyond one line that it goes to a second or third line with the same proper indentation. Any help into the matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will be better with a tabular environment, or a special command to add lines of equations.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I guess so, but how would the `align` feature still maintained within a tabular environment. Wouldn't there be column and row separation issues? And the declaration of the column type for the math section may pose an issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Somehing like this?  (two `&&` before the `\mbox`)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
  {\color{OrangeRed}#1}}

\begin{document}
Let us apply completing the square to the standard form of a quadratic equation, $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

\begin{align*}
  ax^2+bx+c&=0 &&\text{Divide by $a$, the leading coefficient.}&\\[1.25ex]
  x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}&=0 &&\text{Transpose the constant term to the RHS.}&\\[1.25ex]
  x^2+\frac{b}{a}x&=-\frac{c}{a}&&\text{\red{Add $\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)^2$ to both sides.}}&\\[1.25ex]
  x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&&\text{Factor the LHS and simplify the RHS.}&\\[1.25ex]
  \left(x+\frac{b}{a}\right)^2&=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}&&\text{Take the square root of both sides.}&\\[1.25ex]
  x+\frac{b}{a}&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&&\text{Solve for $x$.}&\\[1.25ex]
  x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&&\text{\textbf{Quadratic Formula}.}&
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: since `amsmath` is being used, i suggest using `\text{...}` rather than `\mbox`.

Comment: This seems to do the job. I will wait and see if there are more feedback from the community and then will accept your answer. The question then would be: How do we deal with long descriptions while maintaining proper display?

Comment: @azentina - perhaps `minipage` helps

Answer (score 6):

Package [`witharrows`](http://ctan.org/pkg/witharrows) provides a new environment `WithArrows` similar to `align` where it's possible to use command `\Arrow` to print some text beside an arrow going from one line to another one.

Here you have the possible result with OP's examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta, bending, decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{witharrows}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{OrangeRed}#1}}

\begin{document}
Let us show that by completing the square, we can achieve this.
\[        \begin{WithArrows}
        f(x)&=ax^2+bx+c \Arrow{Factor $a$ from $ax^2+bx$. Do you know why?}\\
            &=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\right)+c \Arrow[tikz=OrangeRed]{Complete the square by adding $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$.} \\
            &=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\red{\frac{b^2}{4a^2}} \right)+c\red{-a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}\Arrow{Factor and simplify.}\\
            &=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\\
            &=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\\
            &=a(x-h)^2+k
        \end{WithArrows}
\] \end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{%
{\color{OrangeRed}#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta, bending, decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
Let us apply completing the square to the standard form of a quadratic equation, $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

\[\begin{WithArrows}
    ax^2+bx+c&=0 \Arrow{Divide by $a$, the leading coefficient.}\\
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}&=0 \Arrow{Transpose the constant term to the RHS.}\\
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x&=-\frac{c}{a} \Arrow[tikz=OrangeRed]{Add $\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)^2$ to both sides.}\\
    x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}&=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2} \Arrow{Factor the LHS and simplify the RHS.}\\
    \left(x+\frac{b}{a}\right)^2&=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2} \Arrow{Take the square root of both sides.}\\
    x+\frac{b}{a}&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \Arrow{Solve for $x$.}\\
    x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
    \end{WithArrows}
\] \end{document}
```

Note: Package documentation doesn't mention it, but we should load `TikZ` and `calc, arrows.meta, bending, decorations.pathreplacing` tikzlibraries to use `WithArrows` environment.