# Preventing `\intertext` from altering `split` alignment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, split

I use the `split` environment for multiline equations:
[image]

Unfortunately when I try to provide description of steps with `\intertext` (in contrast to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33059/123888) it is possible), the alignment seems to be broken:
[image]

How may I fix this (preferably centering the description too)?

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      a &= f(b) \\
\intertext{because $f \equiv g$}
        &= g(b)
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I use `pdflatex` v. 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14

[EDIT]

I have found a question [Describing steps in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/describing-steps-in-an-equation) but the answer would not be applicable as the question is about `align*` environment.
I need to be able to refer to the whole equation, which makes `align` environment unsuitable too.

Comment: You can use `align` and end a row with `\nonumber`, the label wouldn't be vertically centred, but you'd have only one label.

Comment: @Skillmon Does `\intertext` work within `align`?

Comment: @Sigur yes, pretty well I think.

Comment: @Sigur may you write that as an answer?

Comment: @abukaj, me? I'm not the author of any answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flalign` and `\notag` to mimic `\intertext`. But I'd prefer the second layout:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


 \begin{flalign}
 & & a &= f(b) \notag\\
 & \rlap{because $f \equiv g$} & & \\
& & & = g(b) \notag & &
 \end{flalign}
\vspace{1cm} 

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
 & & a &= f(b) \\
& & & = g(b) & &\rlap{\hspace{3em} because $f \equiv g$}
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]